# Resize effect only works when resizing from a small window to a larger window and not other way round

Tags: jquery, resize

https://jsfiddle.net/uk2p7m6z/4/

```
  $( window ).resize(function() {
   if ( $(window).width() > 630) {
   $("#home-right").css({'height':($("#info_section").height()+'px')});
   }

 });
```

I am using the code above to cause the height of a particular div (#home-right) to be the same size of another div ("info_section) at windows which have a size larger than 630px.  This works when resizing from a smaller window to a larger window, but not the other way round.  What is a possible solution?

Comment: Thats what you have written in your If condition code. your condition will only be satisfied when enlarging from a small window.

Comment: How do I cause the reverse to be possible?

Comment: Do you just want to attach it to resize or does the width matter?

Comment: another suggestion: why not use $("#home-right").height($("#info_section").height());

Comment: @kurt - both are important, but width is more important.